# FFmpeg command works locally but not on Azure Batch Service

Tags: azure, ffmpeg, azure-batch

I have a command that generates a video with background and text on it with FFmpeg and would like to render it using Azure Batch Service. Locally my command works:

> ./ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=green:s=854x480:d=7 -vf "[in]drawtext=fontsize=46:fontcolor=White:text=dfdhjf dhjf dhjfh djfh djfh:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=((h-text_h)/2)-48,drawtext=fontsize=46:fontcolor=White:text= djfh djfh djfh djfh djf jdhfdjf hjdfh djfh jd fhdj:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2,drawtext=fontsize=46:fontcolor=White:text=fh:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=((h-text_h)/2)+48[out]" -y StoryA.mp4

while the one generated programatically with C# and added as a task in batch service retursn failure:

> cmd /c %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_ffmpeg#3.4%\ffmpeg-3.4-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=green:s=854x480:d=7 -vf "[in]drawtext=fontsize=46:fontcolor=White:text=dfdhjf dhjf dhjfh djfh djfh:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=((h-text_h)/2)-48,drawtext=fontsize=46:fontcolor=White:text= djfh djfh djfh djfh djf jdhfdjf hjdfh djfh jd fhdj:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2,drawtext=fontsize=46:fontcolor=White:text=fh:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=((h-text_h)/2)+48[out]" -y StoryA.mp4

The ffmpeg configuration works, and also the Pool as I've already tested it with simpler ffmpeg commands which had input and output files. This command doesnt have input file, maybe that is part of the problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your ffmpeg command requires an input file as you suggest, then that file needs to be a part of the [CloudTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.cloudtask?view=azure-dotnet) specification (or other means of ingressing it onto the Batch compute node such as Job Preparation or Start Task if it makes sense) as a [ResourceFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.cloudtask.resourcefiles?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Batch_CloudTask_ResourceFiles).

These resource files should be placed into Azure Blob storage. Generate a SAS URL (with appropriate read permission and sufficient end time) and use that as the ResourceFile's [BlobSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.resourcefile.blobsource?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Batch_ResourceFile_BlobSource).

Comment: with input file it may work, but i wanted to use the command as is without input file